# How to insert Khmer text into SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP2 for a database in which I need to write either Khmer Unicode or English letters.

And I code website by Codeigniter.

My database is using Colattion: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Type Column Name : nvarchar(250).

Query via Codeigniter php:

> insert into Genres
>   (Name)
>   values(N'ការបង្ហាញ')

But in my database when I right click on table, select edit top 200 . The result for Name in table look like this:

> áž€áž¶ážšáž”áž„áŸ’áž áž¶áž‰

I want my result at Name Column is : `ការបង្ហាញ`

How to insert Khmer Text still not change in database?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the type of the column Name? How do you check if the text is correct in the table?

Comment: I want my result at Name Column is : ការបង្ហាញ

Comment: Could you answer my questions? Here's working example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09ea82

Comment: Type Column Name : nvarchar(250). 
I check result by right click on Table . select Edit Top 200

Comment: When you run the same query directly in the server manager, does it store correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me if I change the collation of the table:
[image]
[image]